# How to find nearest nearest place by lat long quickly

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my script, it takes to much time to give output

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = long2 - long1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km

def find_nearest(lat, long):
    distances = bts.apply(
        lambda row: dist(lat, long, row['lat'], row['lon']), 
        axis=1)
    return bts.loc[distances.idxmin(), 'sitename']

airport_hospital_1['sitename'] = airport_hospital_1.apply(
    lambda row: find_nearest(row['lat'], row['lon']), 
    axis=1)
```

Is there any way to make this code faster

Comment: what's your question? does the code not work or something?

Comment: you'd better describe your data structure a little. currently i can only infer you're using pandas. a fast algorithm also need good data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html):

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

# bts
N = 25000
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sitename': 'site' + pd.RangeIndex(1, N+1).astype(str),
                    'lat': np.random.uniform(30, 65, N),
                    'lon': np.random.uniform(-150, -70, N)})

# airport_hospital_1
N = 2000
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'name' + pd.RangeIndex(1, N+1).astype(str),
                    'lat': np.random.uniform(30, 65, N),
                    'lon': np.random.uniform(-150, -70, N)})

# bts
coords = np.radians(df1[['lat', 'lon']])
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
tree = BallTree(coords, metric=dist)

# airport_hostpital_1
coords = np.radians(df2[['lat', 'lon']])
distances, indices = tree.query(coords, k=1)

df2['sitename'] = df1.iloc[indices.ravel()]['sitename'].values
```

Output:

```
          name        lat         lon   sitename
0        name1  32.109678 -129.168059  site15027
1        name2  54.597830  -72.638636   site1745
2        name3  30.280831 -132.000681   site8412
3        name4  35.490756 -128.500015  site22097
4        name5  55.455771  -83.004763  site21841
...        ...        ...         ...        ...
1995  name1996  56.375947  -95.854305  site12061
1996  name1997  52.222642  -80.091020   site2779
1997  name1998  41.023596 -135.235087    site191
1998  name1999  45.358313 -137.822065  site18762
1999  name2000  31.712401 -131.267527   site2479

[2000 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Performance**

```
>>> %timeit tree.query(coords, k=1)
18.3 ms ± 64.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

To be faster, you should use compiled code.

[`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/index.html) allows to calculate a distance between 2 points: ([`Geod.line_length`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.line_length))

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> g = pyproj.Geod(ellps="WGS84")
>>> g.line_length([0, 1], [45, 46])
135869.0912468657
```

```
def nearest(pt, pts):
    g = pyproj.Geod(ellps="WGS84")
    return min(pts, key=lambda x: g.line_length((pt[0], x[0]), (pt[1], x[1])))


pt = nearest((5, 15), ((6, 14), (7, 15), (8, 16)))
print(pt)
```

Give `(6, 14)`