# Python finding closest location

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project whereby I am plotting longitude & latitude on a map. Upon plotting I am then entering a location and I would like my python model to identify the 3 closest locations to the user.

I have looked at geopandas but have had no luck. How can I make the model output the 3 closest longitudes/latitudes?

Comment: Do you want to select the three closest points on the screen, or by actual geographical distance from the [lat, long] coordinates selected?

Comment: Clarify closest. Straight-line closest? Accounting for the curve of the Earth? Driving/walking closest? And what does "3 closest longitudes/latitudes" mean. Are these in a database?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. If OP need to find the 3 nearest places around a user, I think the curve of the Earth does matter :)

Comment: @Corralien Yeah, probably. Just poking for more details.

Comment: You can use `BallTree`. Check my answer from a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554356/15239951. You just have to change `k=1` with `k=3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find nearest nearest place by lat long quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553537/how-to-find-nearest-nearest-place-by-lat-long-quickly)

Comment: @TomMcLean the three closest points by actual geographical distance.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the data is in the form of csv files containing latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Build a distance formula

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, sqrt, atan2

def dms(degrees, minutes, seconds):
    """ Convert degrees minutes and seconds to radians """
    return radians(degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600)

def dist(p, q, R=6_371):
    """ Compute distance between two points on a sphere.

    Haversine formula:
        a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
        c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
        d = R ⋅ c
    where:
        φ is latitude
        λ is longitude
        R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)

    Example:

        >>> p = dms(50, 3, 59), dms(5, 42, 53) # 50° 03′ 59″
        >>> q = dms(58, 38, 38), dms(3, 4, 12) # 58° 38′ 38″
        >>> round(dist(p, q), 1)
        968.9

    """
    # https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/philamg.html
    phi_p, lam_p = p
    phi_q, lam_q = q
    delta_phi = phi_q - phi_p
    delta_lam = lam_q - lam_p
    a = sin(delta_phi / 2)**2 + cos(phi_p) * cos(phi_q) * sin(delta_lam / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    return R * c
```

## Step 2:  Compute the three closest points

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from functools import partial

answer = nsmallest(3, locations, key=partial(dist, user_location))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) from sklearn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

# Dataset
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'place': 'place' + pd.RangeIndex(1, N+1).astype(str),
                   'lat': np.random.uniform(30, 35, N),
                   'lon': np.random.uniform(-150, -145, N)})

coords = np.radians(df[['lat', 'lon']])
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
tree = BallTree(coords, metric=dist)

# User coordinate
user = [32.109643, -148.167012]
coords = np.radians(user)

# Query the database
distances, indices = tree.query([coords], k=3)
out = df.iloc[indices[0]]
```

Output:

```
# Nearest places around [32.109643, -148.167012]
>>> out
     place        lat         lon
9  place10  32.267336 -148.225587
5   place6  31.269928 -148.293427
7   place8  31.667689 -149.197724
```

Comment: @Hamzah. I hope this help

Comment: What do I need to do differently if I have my data locally in the form of csv files?

Comment: `pd.read_csv`? Update your post with a sample of your data and the user coordinate.