# Find Closest Rows by Lat, Lon and Iterations in Pandas

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, matching, nearest-neighbor

i'm trying to develop a new dataframe (df3) after comparing two dataframes - df1, df2. My df1 looks like this:

```
                num       step       latitude           longitude        time                     height   valid_time           windspeed
0              1              0 days   46.0        -122.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          1.2482048
1              1              0 days   45.5        -121.5    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          0.34045473
2              1              0 days   45.0        -121.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          0.63618374
3              2              0 days   46.0        -122.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          0.79829866
4              2              0 days   45.5        -121.5    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          0.7331676
5              2              0 days   45.0        -121.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          1.3981003
6              3              0 days   46.0        -122.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          1.0158184
7              3              0 days   45.5        -121.5    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          1.1108123
8              3              0 days   45.0        -121.0    2023-08-23          10.0        2023-08-23          3.4528110
```

My matching or reference dataframe - df2 looks like this:

```
        site  latitude  longitude
0  Stevenson     45.69    -121.89
1  Rainier       45.00    -115.00
```

I'm trying to develop a pyhton script to filter df1 based on each set of 'latitude' and 'longitude' in df2 and for each 'num' and 'valid_time'. So, 'df3' should look like this:

[image]

I've tried MANY things. Here is the latest and the error:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
df1 = pf_new
df2 = df_sites

# Function to calculate Haversine distance between two sets of coordinates
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(np.radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    r = 6371  # Radius of Earth in kilometers
    return c * r

    
distances = cdist(df1[['latitude','longitude']],df2[['latitude','longitude']],haversine)
closest_row_indices = np.argmin(distances, axis=0)
    

df3 = df1.iloc[closest_row_indices].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df3)
```

And, the error below. Thank you for any ideas as to how to proceed!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[22], line 16
    distances = cdist(df1[['latitude','longitude']],df2[['latitude','longitude']],haversine)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:2933 in cdist
    return _cdist_callable(XA, XB, metric=metric, out=out, **kwargs)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:2604 in _cdist_callable
    dm[i, j] = metric(XA[i], XB[j], **kwargs)

TypeError: haversine() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lat2' and 'lon2'
```

Comment: "filtering" =  making a subset of df1 data based on closest value of latitude and longitude for each value of "num" and "valid_time".

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

```
TypeError: haversine() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lat2' and 'lon2'
```

`lat2` and `lon2` are not set when `cdist` calls `haversine` function so you have an insufficient number of parameters. It's because `lat1` contains the values for latitude/longitude of `df1` and `lat2` for `df2`.

Use the code below to fix it:

```
def haversine(coord1, coord2):
    (lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2) = coord1, coord2
    # the rest of your code

distances = ...
closest_row_indices = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)  # modify the axis here

# Get site name by position (and not label): iloc vs loc
df1['site'] = df2.iloc[closest_row_indices, df2.columns.get_loc('site')].values
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   num    step  latitude  longitude        time  height  valid_time  windspeed       site
0    1  0 days      46.0     -122.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   1.248205  Stevenson
1    1  0 days      45.5     -121.5  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   0.340455  Stevenson
2    1  0 days      45.0     -121.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   0.636184  Stevenson
3    2  0 days      46.0     -122.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   0.798299  Stevenson
4    2  0 days      45.5     -121.5  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   0.733168  Stevenson
5    2  0 days      45.0     -121.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   1.398100  Stevenson
6    3  0 days      46.0     -122.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   1.015818  Stevenson
7    3  0 days      45.5     -121.5  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   1.110812  Stevenson
8    3  0 days      45.0     -121.0  2023-08-23    10.0  2023-08-23   3.452811  Stevenson
```

Details:

```
>>> distances
array([[ 35.50785241, 556.58217101],
       [ 36.97464075, 511.72360862],
       [103.55808238, 471.6522885 ],
       [ 35.50785241, 556.58217101],
       [ 36.97464075, 511.72360862],
       [103.55808238, 471.6522885 ],
       [ 35.50785241, 556.58217101],
       [ 36.97464075, 511.72360862],
       [103.55808238, 471.6522885 ]])
```

As a side note, using Haversine distance is right to take into account the curvature of the earth but it's valuable when you compute long distances. If you use Euclidean distance (default of `cdist`), the drift is 8cm per km, so for 35km, you have an inaccuracy of less than 3 meters (2.88m). Except if your sites are really closed, I don't think it's very useful to use the Haversine distance (IMHO).

A most important point, there is a more efficient way to find the nearest site. You can use spatial partitioning. I already answered to this kind of question:

With [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) (scikit-learn):

- [Matching geographic coordinates between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72134886/15239951)
- [How to find nearest nearest place by lat long quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71553537/15239951)

With [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) (scipy):

- [Find the dealer nearest to the given customer location...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67133408/15239951)